# How to trigger a specific task when Back Button is clicked in Browser EVERYTIME?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to trigger a specific task, like change the CSS of the element when every time user clicks on the browser's Back button.

Luckily SO got my back with the code below, which triggers when a user clicks on the back button and dees the task.

But however, this trigger on the back button click only works once per page load. Hence, the function().

Can anyone help me with how to make it get triggered whenever the back button is pressed?

**Code goes as :**

```
$(function() {
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('', null, './');
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
         // My stuff
        });
     }
});
```

*Any help is greatly appreciated*.

Comment: Have you tried window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {} which might work both for the browser's back button and refresh button? If this helps in anyway.

Comment: Could you try replacing `''` with `Date.now()` in `pushState()`?

Comment: @Rojo Nothing in particular changed

Answer (score 0):

Use event listener , i dont know how to do it in jQuery, the code will look like this

```
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('', null, './');
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
         // My stuff
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: OP has that eventlistener just in jquery

Comment: @Rojo  What's OP?

Comment: OP is original poster or original post